# Unsigned Numbers In Python

Tags: python

As as part of cryptography course, I run into a lot of large numbers( 128 bits or more). While my course being largely mathematical doesn't dwell much on the implementation side of the field, I am trying to implement some simple algorithms in my free time.

Obviosuly, the first stumbling block has been figuring out different ways to represent large numbers (128 bits or mode). So far, I have used Python's ctype which gives me unsigned ints upto 64bits.

For example: How do I deal with keys/data blocks which are more than 64bits? For example, something like:

```
  A56BABCD00000000FFFFFFFFABCDEF01
```

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read **anything** about Python? It supports long arithmetic already.

Comment: python says your number is written as `219881679602189885463659373782260117249L` in decimal notation.

Comment: @m0nhawk I was looking at Pythons support for unsigned numbers, and I don't think long arithmatic supports that. Hence my use of the ctypes module.

Comment: @feverDream what do you mean by "unsigned" in this case? What particular properties of "unsigned" you needed?

Comment: @m0nhawk
unsigned because most of the operations on the data-types are binary shift (left and right)

Comment: To the downvoters and close-voters: This question is salvageable, based on the latest comment (though perhaps it is a duplicate; I don't have the time to check carefully at the moment). @feverDream: You need to frame this question in terms of fixed bit-widths and deliberately truncating overflows and underflows. If you don't rewrite this question, it will seem like you have no idea what you're talking about. (And just changing the title to "unsigned numbers" is probably not enough. You need to seriously revise the text.)

Comment: @JohnY
Thanks! I think I realized that. I should have been more explicit about my usecase.

Answer (score 2):

Python already supports arbitrarily long integers ([implementation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/longintrepr.h)). Try this on the command line:

```
>>> 0xA56BABCD00000000FFFFFFFFABCDEF01
219881679602189885463659373782260117249L
```